# if not OffsetArrays.jl then how to store and access array with irregular for loop?

Tags: julia

I have the following awkward for loop, and e.g. `kreps=(8, 7, 6)`, a tuple of Int's. I pre-computed a multi-dimensional array `kvec_wts` that holds a Float depending on `kreps`. With [OffsetArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/OffsetArrays.jl), I can call `kvec_wts[ka, kb, kc]` inside the loop very beautifully!

```
for kc=-kreps[3]:kreps[3], kb = -kreps[2]:kreps[2], ka = 0:kreps[1]             
    if ka == 0                                                                  
        if kb < 0                                                               
            continue                                                            
        end                                                                     
        if kb == 0 && kc <= 0                                                   
            continue                                                            
        end                                                                     
    end

  # do tons of computation involving `kvec_wts[ka, kb, kc]`
end
```

Here's how I allocate with OffsetArrays.jl:

```
kvec_wts = OffsetArray(zeros(Float64, 
                        kreps[1] + 1,
                        2 * kreps[2] + 1,
                        2 * kreps[3] + 1),
                       0:kreps[1], 
                       -kreps[2]:kreps[2],
                       -kreps[3]:kreps[3])
```

After some profiling and finding [this post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/performance-of-offsetarrays/5769?u=raminammour) showing there are performance hits, what is a more beautiful way to store and access the array `kvec_wts` inside the loop?

The problem is that awkward for loop I have appears in a few spots in my code, and it seems dangerous to assume an indexing that is dependent on the order of the for loop... Right? Is there a way to write a code for the for loop? Would the solution be a custom iterator, or a macro of some sort to always make sure the same for loop is reproduced, then I can just have a 1D array for `kvec_wts`? Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, does your profiling actually point to those particular function calls as your bottleneck?

Comment: Also for the performance issues, have you tried the `@unsafe` trick mentioned in the OffsetArrays readme?

Comment: The `@unsafe` method to avoid bounds checking gave me drastic speed-up! I am not seeing any performance issues now. So now my question is just... what would one do without the OffsetArrays.jl package?